# How to fill UITableView after Initialization

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I read tutorial here
http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-part-1-uitableview-using-nsarray/

which shows how to fill a UITableView at initialization. I can't find tut to do so after initialization (for example when User has clicked on a button).

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would just update the data source and reload the table view.

Following that tutorial, you would do it like so:

```
- (IBAction)myButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    self.arrayData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"iPhone", @"iPod", @"MacBook", @"MacBook Pro", @"iMac"];
    [self.tblSimpleTable reloadData]
}
```

This will tell the `UITableView` to reload the data source and adjust the amount of sections, rows etc.

Note that you might prefer to use a `NSMutableArray` instead.

`[self.mutableArrayData addObject:@"iMac"];`

Comment: Thanks, does it mean doing this "cell.text = [arryData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];" implicitely bind the table to arryData  FOREVER ?

Comment: What do I do if at init I do not want any value, how do I declare the binding then ?

Comment: Setting `cell.text` will set the text of the `titleLabel`. This will be set everytime the cell becomes visible. If you want to have an empty array when initializing, you would do `self.arrayData = [NSMutableArray] alloc] init]` (assuming that you want your array to be mutable) You might benefit from reading this document. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7